# Binding (fn.call) context to a function in an object causes an error

Tags: typescript

I have code like this -

```
const foo = {
  bar(): void {
    window.console.log(this.lorem);
  }
};

foo.bar.call({ lorem: 'ipsum' });
```

...and TypeScript says this -

```
Property 'lorem' does not exist on type { bar(): void; }
```

[image]

How may I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#declaring-this-in-a-function) parameter:

```
const foo = {
  bar(this: { lorem: string }): void {
    window.console.log(this.lorem);
  }
};
```